# FlurryAds: No ads available from server for this space. IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, flurry, flurry-analytics

I have created an app universal ios app in Flurry.com and created a native adSpace. Given the API key and adSpace name as described in the documentation. But I got Error when i run the app and nothing happens. Error log is Given below.

Load AdUnit Timed out

Picked cached ad unit 0x0 with guid (null)

Successfully parsed ad request schema

Successfully created ad request.

Sending AdRequest....

Sending AdRequest of size 1224....

Flurry: HTTP connection delegate received response

```
[ { URL: https://ads.flurry.com/v14/getAds.do } { status code: 200, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 78;
"Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
Date = "Wed, 04 May 2016 05:20:08 GMT";
"FM-Checksum" = "-909430395";
"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=10";
Server = nginx;
} }]
```

This is a ad response of len 78

Successfully parsed ad response schema

Error in AdRequest: [Database has no section id for ad space]

FlurryAdCache: skipping adunit with empty or nil adspace
******* logAdEvent: **

```
[ unfilled(4), T:28460] 
** [S:1462339177513, RS:1462339177513 ID:1, GUID (null), {(
" ** [ unfilled(4), T:28460] "
)} transmitted {{
}} ]**
```

Native Ad for Space [FlotillaNative1] Received Error # [1], with description: `[Error Domain=FlurryAds Code=104 "FlurryAds: No ads available from server for this space." UserInfo=0x1a94a070 {NSLocalizedDescription=FlurryAds: No ads available from server for this space.}]` ================

What does it mean?

Comment: see this https://github.com/flurry/ios-AdIntegrationSamples/issues/6

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I got this error `FlurryAds: No ads available from server for this space." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=FlurryAds: No ads available from server for this space.}]`

Comment: @MonikaPatel - it is a bug in that sdk , try once in new sdk

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I'm using latest SDK. That is 7.6.6

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik are you there?

Comment: @MonikaPatel - yes

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik You know any solution of my error

Comment: @MonikaPatel - i also searched but I am not get any results related to this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122156/discussion-between-monika-patel-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 2):

The line in the error log that identifies the real problem is this one:

> Error in AdRequest: [Database has no section id for ad space]

This is likely a fault on Flurry's side. When you were creating the Ad Unit, Flurry failed to send the section id to the ad provider. To fix this, try going back to `Flurry -> App Publishing -> Applications & Ad Units`. Then find your ad space, click it to get to [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAczh.png), and then click `Submit` at the bottom to re-save your ad space. Scroll to the top of this page and make sure there is a green bar saying `Ad unit has been saved successfully.`

This should correctly send your section id to the app provider and you should be able to receive ads within an hour (takes some time to go through).

Comment: I got error when fetch native video ad  Error in AdRequest: [Ad request view type doesn't match ad space placement] @Coby Anderson

Comment: I got error when fetch native video ad  Error in AdRequest: [Ad request view type doesn't match ad space placement] @Claudius